# Python, aiogram. Как сделать чтобы 2 handlera на одно и тоже сообщение выполнялись одновременно?

Tags: python, aiogram, handlers

Есть 2 таких хандлера, из них выполняется первый встречающийся в коде. Как сделать, чтобы они оба выполнились?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: средствами aiogram - подозреваю никак :)

Comment: Ну просто запустите его как функцию в том хендлере который срабатывает

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Это не реализовать декораторами.

Единственный, пожалуй, способ - вызывать из одной фк-ции другую. Пример:

```
@rate_limit(limit=15)
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_warning(msg: Message):

    await filter(msg)

    ...
    #дальше уже код самой функции
```